# C++ unknown variable type. Should I use template?

Tags: c++, templates, typing

I'm trying to create a class that will parse a file in C++.
However the file is actually in 2 files, the header and the raw data.

The header contains the data type of the raw data (it can be int, double, float, etc...).
I want to create a variable in my class that will store the raw data.
The processing will be the same, no matter the data type.

Should I use a template to do this ? Isn't it overkill to use a templated class for just 1 variable ?

Thank you.

Comment: `Should I use a template to do this ? ` What are the other options before you?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe just declare a void pointer, allocate necessary memory, copy raw data, and then cast the pointer base on the data type.
It's not really clean, but I feel like using a template for just one variable is not optimal. Is it ?

Comment: `boost::variant` - no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: *Isn't it overkill to use a templated class for just 1 variable?* Quite many containers have just one templated type/variable and it's not overkill at all.

Comment: So, boost::variant or template ? That's mostly why I asked the question. I know there is other way to do it, but I don't know which one is the 'right' answer (or the cleanest).
Thank you.

Comment: The types of variables must be known at compile-time, so this doesn't seem like a viable option if the type is determined by the contents of the file.

Comment: The type is defined by the file, but the list of possibilities are known at compile-time (short, int, double, float and unsigned), so I think it's still possible to use both (templates and boost::variant), right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates could certainly help you here. They offer a way to reduce repetition of that processing which you say is the same for all types.

Whether you "should" use them is of course a more difficult question, as is whether it's overkill - both are matters of opinions, but common use would suggest that the use of just one variable would not be the factor that would decide that.

If the contents of the files containing different types need to be processed into the same container or if a file can contain more than one type, then maybe boost variant would be more suitable.

Since you read the types from file, those types are known at runtime, but since the list of options is known at compile time you can check the type in the file and pass in the type.

```
if(typeFromFile == headerValueForint)
{
    processFile<int>();
}
else if (typeFromFile == headerValueFordouble)
{
    processFile<double>();
}
```

However as all the types you list are numeric (and I wonder how the processing could really be the same if there's any other non-numeric types) you could decide to read all the values in as doubles - with suitable range checking. It might take up more memory but the impact of that depends on what the processing actually involves.

Comment: The thing is I have a header file, telling me the number of dimensions, the  size of each dimensions, the type of data, etc...
Then I have a binary file (raw data) that I have to read based on these information. To make it easier, I want to read the header, and create an array (with the proper type, dimensions, sizes, etc...) to put all the raw data in it, so I only have to read the file once, and then I can access data in the array. So at compile time, I don't really know the size or type of the array, but I know it at runtime.

Comment: OK, with regard type, that's what my example code shows. A run time check that will call the templated code with the correct type. The actual call will probably be different to my example as it will most likely take some parameters. In terms of size of the collection, that can be set at runtime easily enough.

Comment: Oh okay, I misinterpreted what you suggested. That was indeed my initial plan, but I wasn't sure creating a new templated class for just a single templated variable was a good idea. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What about using **function overloading**?  You said the processing is the same, so... I think you could.  I use them sometimes to do this kind of stuff.

Example:

Header.h

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void function(int x);
    void function(double x);
    void function(string x);
    void function(char x);
};
```

The compiler will know what function to use, depending of the value that you are sending (passing) to it.

Comment: Isn't it an issue if you need to call some subfunctions ? You probably need to overload them too, right ?
Let say I need to access my data by coordinates ( get(x,y,z) ), then I will need to create a function for each data type (as the type return might be different).
I start to think a templated class would actually be easier. Thanks.

Comment: Given that the processing will be the same, the overloaded function option is going to result in a lot of (near) repetition - each will differ only in where the type of parameter x appears. This is exactly where templates help you - by replacing that "whatever input type" bit of code with the template parameter and allowing all versions to be implemented by the same source code.

Comment: The problem is that I have to store these data. I'm reading a big text file, and to improve efficiency, I want to store these data in a variable first, then make some processing on it. I don't know exactly yet what the processing will be.
To be more concrete, I'm creating a program that parse some files, which could have different data dimensions, data type, etc...
Let's say for example I want to average values on a given region, I think it's easier to have a templated array containing the values, and a templated averaging function, instead of overloading everything.